# ¿Porque no puedo cargar esta plantilla de Boostrap4 en Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap

Resulta que no puedo cargar una plantilla de boostrap4 y rails me arroja el siguiente problema

```
Showing /Users/Brian/Desktop/nuevo/final_proyect/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #10 raised:

couldn't find file 'main' with type 'text/css'
Checked in these paths: 
  /Users/Brian/Desktop/nuevo/final_proyect/app/assets/config
  /Users/Brian/Desktop/nuevo/final_proyect/app/assets/images
  /Users/Brian/Desktop/nuevo/final_proyect/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/Brian/Desktop/nuevo/final_proyect/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts
  /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actioncable-5.2.0/lib/assets/compiled
  /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activestorage-5.2.0/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionview-5.2.0/lib/assets/compiled
  /Users/Brian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/turbolinks-source-5.1.0/lib/assets/javascripts
  /Users/Brian/Desktop/nuevo/final_proyect/node_modules
  /Users/Brian/Desktop/nuevo/final_proyect/vendor/css/font-awesome/img
Extracted source (around line #13):
11
12
13
14
15
16

 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require main
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap
```

Comment: Pero lo que pones no es suficiente info. Donde tienes la plantilla, cual es el código del  application.html.erb, etc

Answer (score 0):

El error dice:

```
couldn't find file 'main' with type 'text/css'
```

Esta no encuentra el archivo 'main.css' dentro de la carpeta `app/assets/stylesheets` asegurate que este ese archivo o si no lo necesitas quitar el `*= require main`.